# How to use str_which to select rows which contain a string from a Vector

Tags: r, stringr

I have a Table like this

```
name    <- c("Goku","Vegeta","Jiren","Gohan","Piccolo","Kurinin","Trunks","Buu","Frieza","Cell","Muten","Gotens")
surname <- c("San","San","San","San","San","San","San","Majin","Evil","San","Roshi","San")
email   <- c("goku@gmail.com","vegeta@gmail.com","jiren@patrol.ch","gohan@gmail.com","piccolo@gmail.com","kurinin@gmail.com","Trunks@gmail.com","buu@babidi.com","frieza@rampage.usa","cell@rampage.usa","muten@gmail.com","gotens@gmail.com")

table <- data.frame(name, surname, email, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I have a Vector with different endings in email adresses. I want to find all rows which use email adresses with this endings

```
searchvector = c("@patrol.ch", "@babidi.com", "@rampage.usa")
searchvector = as.character(searchvector)
```

There are two ways I tried to search for the rows containg the searchvector:

A. Using str_detect:

```
table[str_detect(table$email, "@patrol.ch|@babidi.com|@rampage.usa"), ]
```

This gives me the correct result

```
name surname              email  
3   Jiren     San    jiren@patrol.ch  
8     Buu   Majin     buu@babidi.com  
9  Frieza    Evil frieza@rampage.usa  
10   Cell     San   cell@rampage.usa
```

B. But when using str_which, I always only get two rows

```
table[str_which(table$email, searchvector), ]
table[str_which(table$email, c("@patrol.ch", "@babidi.com", "@rampage.usa")), ]
```

I get this result in both cases:

```
name surname email  
8 Buu Majin buu@babidi.com
9 Frieza Evil frieza@rampage.usa
```

Why is that? And how can I use str_which to do what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

According to `?str_which`, it is a wrapper function

> str_which() is a wrapper around which(str_detect(x, pattern)), and is equivalent to grep(pattern, x).

Inorder to get the same output, we need a single string in `pattern`.  It can he created with `paste` and specifying the `collapse` argument to `|`

```
table[str_which(table$email, paste(searchvector, collapse="|")), ]
#     name surname              email
#3   Jiren     San    jiren@patrol.ch
#8     Buu   Majin     buu@babidi.com
#9  Frieza    Evil frieza@rampage.usa
#10   Cell     San   cell@rampage.usa
```

just like it was created for `str_detect` in the OP's post

If we use the vector as `pattern` in `str_detect`

```
table[str_detect(table$email, searchvector),]
#   name surname              email
#8    Buu   Majin     buu@babidi.com
#9 Frieza    Evil frieza@rampage.usa
```

returns the same output as in `str_which` with OP's code

Regarding the `vectorization` issue with `str_detect`, it is, but here the `length` of the 'email' and 'searchvector' is different.  So, there would be a recycling issue

Comment: "the lengths are different": recycling.

Comment: @nicola  Yes, that is TRUE